# PHP PDO transaction automatic rollBack

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I am just refining some code on one of my applications which I converted from using PHP ADODB library to PDO lately. In adodb once you launched a transaction it automatically rolled back if any exception should arise with queries between the begin and commit commands.

Does PDO also do this. If a method which has a query it it fails between a begin and commit in PDO will the trsaction automatically rollback or does it need to be implicitly called?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to call rollback (and commit) yourself, `PDO` won't do it for you.  Something like this:

```
$pdo = new \PDO(/* ... */);

$pdo->beginTransaction();

try {
    // do stuff..
} catch(\Throwable $e) { // use \Exception in PHP < 7.0
    $pdo->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}

$pdo->commit();
```

PDO will [rollback any open transactions when a script ends](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php), however.

> When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if you have an outstanding transaction, PDO will automatically roll it back.

So the transaction will *probably* get rolled back depending on your application (maybe you have an even listener some place that's going to commit for you?). It's probably a good idea to do an explicit rollback right near where the exception happened.

Comment: But... if you begin transaction, make some inserts and updates and then make ALTER TABLE which fails on row greater than 1, the default action is commit in practice... MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Correct, MySQL DDL queries (like ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, etc) create an implicit commit. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: From PHP.net page, the `beginTransaction()` is inside `try{...}` not outside. Which one is correct? Inside or before `try{..}`?

Comment: @vee The question you have to ask yourself to answer this is: if you get an exception during `beginTransaction()`, do you want to trigger the `catch` block or not? If your `catch` block has a call to `rollBack()`, you might want to have `beginTransaction()` outside the `try` because if `beginTransaction()` fails with an exception, there will be no active transaction to roll back, causing `rollBack()` in the `catch` block to throw an exception too. Might as well let the original exception bubble.

Answer (score 14):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php:

> When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if you have an outstanding transaction, PDO will automatically roll it back. ... if you didn't explicitly commit the transaction, then it is assumed that something went awry, so the rollback is performed for the safety of your data.

Nevertheless, it is a good practice to explicitly rollback a transaction in case of error. See this question for more details: [If an PHP PDO transaction fails, must I rollback() explicitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001698/if-an-php-pdo-transaction-fails-must-i-rollback-explicitely)

Comment: Thanks for the info, very interesting in fact and exactly what I was looking for. Don't know how I missed it in the docs. Thanks again.